# Display sum of all data in line graph

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, graph, morris.js

How to display total sum of data "Sales" in a function?

```
    var line = new Morris.Line({
        element          : 'line-chart',
        resize           : true,
        data             : [
          { y: '2016 Q1', Sales: 3000 },
          { y: '2016 Q2', Sales: 4000 },
          { y: '2016 Q3', Sales: 5000 },
          { y: '2016 Q4', Sales: 6000 },
        ],
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Try to post your complete function;

Comment: use sum aggregation

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is very straightforward

```
var sum = 0;
data.forEach(o => sum += o.Sales)
```